# Android ZIPALIGN finished with non-zero exit value -1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-assets, zipalign

My android app contain 52 thousand'.mp3' files stored in two different folders in Asset folder.

When I run the app in android studio it throws the following error

```
Asset/Media/Folder_name1/'.mp3'  53k files
Asset/Media/Folder_name2/'.mp3'  53k files
```

**> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:zipalignDebug'.**

> Process 'command '/Users/ubasimo/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/zipalign'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I have removed the mp3 files folder and it run successfully. What is the issue there. is there any constraint for adding the number of files in asset ?

> I have zipped the folder and then also its working fine. But zipping is not suitable in my case.